# How to show a norm identity of a weighted sum

Tags: normed-spaces

I ran across the following identity while reading up on norms. It deals with the square of the $2$-norm of a convex combination. That is, for all $x,y,\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\rho \in [0,1]$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\|\rho x + (1-\rho)y\|^2_2 = \rho\|x\|_2^2 + (1-\rho)\|y\|_2^2 - \rho(1-\rho)\|y-x\|_2^2.
\end{eqnarray}

However, I have not been able to prove the identity by putting together the right order of manipulations. Anyone know how to show the above identity?

Also, it may be obvious with a justification of the identity, but my instinct is that we should be able to extend $\rho$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but again, I don't know how to justify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left hand side equals to 
$$\rho^2\|x\|_2^2 + (1 - \rho)^2\|y\|_2^2 + 2\rho(1 - \rho)x \cdot y.$$
While the right hand side equals to 
\begin{align*}
& \rho\|x\|_2^2 + (1 - \rho)\|y\|_2^2 - \rho(1 - \rho)(\|y\|_2^2 + \|x\|_2^2 - 2y\cdot x) \\
= &[\rho - \rho(1 - \rho)]\|x\|_2^2 + [(1 - \rho) - \rho(1 - \rho)]\|y\|_2^2 + 2\rho(1 - \rho)x \cdot y \\
= & \rho^2\|x\|_2^2 + (1 - \rho)^2\|y\|_2^2 + 2\rho(1 - \rho)x \cdot y.
\end{align*}
The above calculation does not require that $\rho \in [0, 1]$, so your guess is correct.